# Trace/BPT trap: 5 error on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, nlp, rails-activerecord

I'm writing a simple application using the Stanford Core NLP gem.

My simple HTML form has a text box at "/new", and I render the views in my controller as follows:

```
def create
    @text = Text.new(text_params)

    if @text.save
        redirect_to text_path(@text)
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def show
    @text = Text.find(params[:id])
    @text = @text.pos_tagger(@text)
end
```

Just to check that I can get some output from the NLP core gem, this is my Text model:

```
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base

def pos_tagger (text)
    require 'stanford-core-nlp'
    pipeline =  StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit, :pos, :lemma, :parse, :ner, :dcoref)
    text = StanfordCoreNLP::Annotation.new(text)
    newtext = pipeline.annotate(text)
    return newtext
end
end
```

When I run the app, everything is fine until I get to the show page, when I get the following error:

**Processing by TextsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Text Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "texts".* FROM "texts" WHERE "texts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
Trace/BPT trap: 5**

and the application quits.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions for the same problem. This is the third question that I've seen for the same error now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Server crashes Chrome "No Data Received"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047661/rails-server-crashes-chrome-no-data-received)