# Rails Server crashes Chrome "No Data Received"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rake

I have loaded the 'stanford-core-nlp' gem and am trying to use it in my fledgling app.
However, every time I try to show the rendered text, I receive this error message from Chrome and the rails server exits, citing Trace/BPT trap: 5.

I have searched other similar Rails errors but can't find anything that seems to match my situation. The only thing I can think of is that the code below is causing some kind of issue?

```
def pos_tagger (text)
    require 'stanford-core-nlp'
    pipeline =  StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit, :pos, :lemma, :parse, :ner, :dcoref)
    text = StanfordCoreNLP::Annotation.new(text)
    newtext = pipeline.annotate(text)
    return newtext
end
```

Should I - a newbie - back away from using this module and try something else?

Comment: I don't think you want to require the gem in the method.  Try moving `require 'stanford-core-nlp'` to above the class definition.  Also, try opening rails console and going line by line to see what each variable is being assigned and if it is what you expect.

Comment: Trying your suggestion now: error message is still the same... Processing by TextsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bZ7IVKJV/E+LfxKLczNI1jP7ve9PGn/0ZIe00jcxLjE=", "text"=>{"body"=>"hello my friends it has been wonderful speaking to you today"}, "commit"=>"Create Text"}
Killed: 9

Comment: Will investigate the rails console (although am a newbie, not used it before)